# Wordpress / Contact Form 7 - Display list of files

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, contact-form

I'm using Wordpress & Contact Form 7 for a form. The form includes a button that allows multi uploads.

Everything is working fine, however when I attach/upload files with the button it just says "3 files". I would like to display a list that states the filenames.

Is that at all possible using Contact Form 7? Can someone pooint me in the right direction what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the same tag as you put into the File attachments field into the Message body textarea. The tag will be replaced by the file name.